# Use terraform to push docker image to azure container registry

Tags: azure, docker, terraform, azure-container-registry, terraform-provider-docker

I am using terraform to provision the infrastructure for my project in Azure.

Part of the infrastructure is a container registry to store the docker images that will be used by kubernates. Since at the moment everything is provisioned using terraform I am trying to build and push the images too. I found the [`kreuzwerker/docker`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kreuzwerker/docker/latest/docs) provider that maybe can do the job.

For the moment I have this code:

```
provider "docker" {
  registry_auth {
    address  = azurerm_container_registry.example.login_server
    username = azurerm_container_registry.example.admin_username
    password = azurerm_container_registry.example.admin_password
  }
}

resource "docker_registry_image" "example" {
  name          = "example"
  keep_remotely = false

  build {
    context    = path.cwd
    dockerfile = "Dockerfile"
  }
}
```

It seems like the image has been build but when it comes to push it to the registry I get this error:

```
╷
│ Error: resourceDockerRegistryImageCreate: Unable to get authConfig for registry: no auth config found for registry registry-1.docker.io in auth configs: map[string]types.AuthConfig{"***.azurecr.io":types.AuthConfig{Username:"***", Password:"***", Auth:"", Email:"", ServerAddress:"https://***.azurecr.io", IdentityToken:"", RegistryToken:""}}
│ 
│   with docker_registry_image.backend,
│   on docker.tf line 1, in resource "docker_registry_image" "backend":
│    1: resource "docker_registry_image" "backend" {
│ 
╵
```

I think it's trying to push to `registry-1.docker.io` but that's not the correct registry. So I tried

```
provider "docker" {
  host = azurerm_container_registry.example.login_server

  registry_auth {
    address  = azurerm_container_registry.example.login_server
    username = azurerm_container_registry.example.admin_username
    password = azurerm_container_registry.example.admin_password
  }
}
```

But then I get this error:

```
╷
│ Error: Error initializing Docker client: unable to parse docker host `***.azurecr.io`
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker"],
│   on provider.tf line 8, in provider "docker":
│    8: provider "docker" {
│ 
╵
```

How can I use this provider to push the image to the correct ACR?

Comment: You need to name the image properly. "example" will be pushed to dockerhub. Prepend the name of your ACR registry.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: You are right!

Changing `docker_registry_image`'s `name` to "${azurerm_container_registry.example.login_server}/example" worked!

Thanks very much!

Comment: Good that it was that. I'll type it up as an answer and you can accept it to close the QnA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For docker images, the name if the image actually defines which registry will be used to push the image to (or fetch it from). So when you define the image name to be `example`, it will by default go to DockerHub.

In order to send the image to your own registry, wherever that may be, the registry domain must be prepended to the image name, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli?tabs=azure-cli).

In an example taken from the link above, `mcr.microsoft.com/oss/nginx/nginx:1.15.5-alpine` would be pushed to the registry `mcr.microsoft.com` instead of DockerHub.

Comment: Do you also know how the `docker_registry_image.name` should look like to work with AWS ECR? I tried these variants and I get different errors: `<account>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<repository-name>:latest`: Unable to create image, image not found: unable to get digest: Got bad response from registry: 404 Not Found (but the image is created), `<account>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<repository-name>/<image-name>:latest`: "Error pushing docker image: Error pushing image: EOF"

Comment: I figure it out. For AWS, `address` in the provider config has to be `<account>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com`, NOT `<account>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<repository-name>`. About the image name, <account>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<repository-name>:<tag>` is the correct syntax.